# Excel 2010 VBA ActiveChart.SetSourceData Failed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a Excel VBA application which has been working fine in Excel 2003 but failed in Excel 2010.

The relative codes are

```
Public Sub Create_Chart
    Dim c
    Dim OutputText As String
    OutputText = OutputSource
    Workbooks(NewWorkBook).Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        obj.Range(DataRange).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=obj.Range(DataRange)
    End With
End Sub
```

The error message appears when debugger hits ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=objNBR.Range(DataRange) with this window -
[image]

The DataRange in debugger is F2:R2, F3:R3 with the obj pointing to the right Excel form -
[image]

The the ActiveChart is from a template - 
[image]

My debugger shows "ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select" is true.  And ActiveChart and obj are valid objects.

Most important is that Excel 2003 works fine.  I use the debugger to compare the Excel 2003 and 2010 obj and ActiveChart.  And I can not find much different in terms of codes.  I do see my template for the ActiveChart is a bit different in 2003 -
[image]

The original template is exactly the same as shown in 2010 but it has been auto zeroed out during copied to the working sheet in 2003.  That is the only difference I can notice between 2003 and 2010.  I am not sure that can cause this error.

I am not sure whether I have missed any evidence.  The error message does not give much details.  Is there any other ways to get more debug info?

I appreciate it if anyone can help me find the problems and fixes.

Thanks in advance

**Edit1:**  The obj is created in another routine and the DataRange are populeted in that routine -

```
Workbooks.Add
MyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set obj = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

And then the data is inserted to DataRange cells - F2:R2, F3:R3.  I can see the Excel file shown with the correct data.

**Edit2**  The Workbooks(NewWorkBook) in the above sub is generated from these codes and I can see the new Excel with the chart is shown on the screen -

```
Windows(Dir(TemplateFile)).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("C1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("C1").Copy
NewWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Windows(NewWorkBook).Visible = True
```

**Edit3** Use Sid's approach to declare the object first in this way -

```
Public Sub Create_Chart()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim Chrt As chart

    Set wb = Workbooks(NewWorkBook)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    Set objChrt = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    Set Chrt = objChrt.chart

    With wb
        obj.Range(DataRange).NumberFormat = "0.0%"

        'Chrt.Export ("c:\temp\testChrt.gif")

        'With obj.PageSetup
         '   .PrintArea = DataRange
         '   .Zoom = False
         '   .FitToPagesTall = 1
         '   .FitToPagesWide = 1
         '   .Orientation = xlLandscape
       ' End With

       ' obj.PrintOut Copies:=1

        Chrt.SetSourceData Source:=obj.Range(DataRange)
    End With
End Sub
```

The error is exactly the same.  Please notice that I have the commented out codes to print out and save the Chrt and obj.Range(DataRange) objects.  The values are the same as image 2 and image 3 in the above.  So chart and data are there.  I just wonder why "Chrt.SetSourceData Source:=obj.Range(DataRange)" does not work in this case in 2010 but work in 2003.

Comment: What is `obj`? What is `DataRange`? Also instead of using ActiveChart or Activesheet, you might want to create relevant objects and work with it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, obj is the data source sheet to create the chart.  DataRange is the data cells to pull the data from.  In this case, it is F2:R2,F3:R3.

Comment: Try declaring objects and then workign with it?

Comment: Let me know if you want an example?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thanks Siddharth, I added the obj creation codes in the bottom of the topic.  I can see the data are correctly shown in the Excel file like the one of the images I posted.

Comment: See the 3rd sentence in my first comment :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, is it possible to create objects with name in memory?  Please give me an example if you have.  I thought in Excel we have to save it to disk to get a name associated with the relevant objects.  That is why I am using ActiveChart or Activesheet.

Comment: +1 for this question: I'm currently encountering the same problem via 2010 ... going to restart my machine and then check if still a problem. Wonder if Excel's enable_events or calculation state has an impact?

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comments above, this is the way you should declare objects and work with them. You should avoid the use of `Activesheet/Activeworkbook/ActiveChart... etc`

You may also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

This is just an example. Please amend it to suit your needs.

```
Public Sub Create_Chart()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim Chrt As Chart

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set objChrt = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    Set Chrt = objChrt.Chart

    Chrt.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("B2:B3,I2:I3")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sid.  I rewrote the codes with object declaration.  But I still have exact the same error.  I can see ws.Range("B2:B3,I2:I3") has the values in my debugger and Chrt is a valid object.  Is there any way we can get more debugging information in Excel 2010 debugging?

Comment: It's already 3 AM here and I was planning to hit bed. Can we catch up tom on this and I promise to help you :)

Comment: What about the [optional parameter `PlotBy`?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx). Would specifying it have an effect?

Comment: @sancho.s, there is not difference to add PlotBy.  The parameter is optional any way.

Comment: @Don: Ok I am up :) let me know and we can sort this :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Thanks, I added more information as Edit1 - Edit3 in the topic.  Could you please look there to see if you can find anything there.  The data and chart have been loaded as expected before SetSourceData is taken.

Comment: That code looks incomplete? What is `OutputSource`? What is `NewWorkBook`? What is `DataRange`? What is `objNBR`? Also What do you get when you type this `Msgbox objNBR.Range(DataRange).Address` before the line `Chrt.SetSourceData Source:=objNBR.Range(DataRange)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I have removed the irrelevant OutputSource. NewWorkBook is just the name of the Excel workbook holding the template chart (the third image in the topic).  DataRange is "F2:R2, F3:R3" - the worksheet field range (the second image in the topic).  I have renamed objNBR as obj in EDIT3 to be consistent with the codes before.  obj is Excel worksheet having the source data (the second image in the topic).  "Msgbox objNBR.Range(DataRange).Address" shows me "$F$2:$R$2, $F$3:$R$3"

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% that the following is exactly the same problem but I have a feeling it is close.

The following seems like a bug to me - why would `ActiveChart` support a property but an object variable referencing the same chart not support that property?

```
Sub findTheChart()

Dim p_Snapshot As Excel.Workbook
Dim myChartObject As Excel.ChartObject

Set p_Snapshot = Excel.Workbooks("theBookWithTheCharts")

Dim chtName As String
Dim dayNum As Integer
Dim sourceAddress As String
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Excel.Range

Set ws = p_Snapshot.Sheets("theSheetWithTheCharts")
sourceAddress = "$AW$69:$BA$84"

For Each myChartObject In ws.ChartObjects
    chtName = myChartObject.Name

    If (chtName = "Chart_nameGiven") Then
        myChartObject.Activate

        Set r = ws.Range(sourceAddress)
        'myChartObject.SetSourceData Source:=r '<<<<<<<<<<<<doesn't work
        Excel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=r '<<<<<<<<works fine!!!
    End If
Next myChartObject


End Sub
```

Comment: myChartObject is a ChartObject, while ActiveChart is a Chart. myChartObject.Chart is the corresponding Chart.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare extra variables. This works fine:

```
  With ThisWorkbook

  .Sheets(cstrParamTab).ChartObjects("IntradayChart1").Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=.Sheets(cstrChartBaseTab).Range(cstrColTimeStamp & clngTopRow & ":" & cstrColValueClose & plngLastRow), PlotBy:=xlColumns

  End With
```

The variables defining the tabs and range are predefined constants and vars. you can do it like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook

  .Sheets("Parameters").ChartObjects("IntradayChart1").Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=.Sheets("ChartBase").Range("B2:B239"), PlotBy:=xlColumns

  End With
```

but it's not going to work if your chart is dynamic.

Good luck